# ArgumentNullException Was unhandled ....Need a solution in below code

Tags: c#, datagridview

The following code causes a ArgumentNullException.  Why?

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //SELECT Job_no, Order_No, Revision, DesignSpec, Engine_Type, LE_IN_Designer, 
        //       CPH_Designer, Exp_Del_Week, Action_code, Rev_Description, Ref_pattern, 
        //       Name_of_mock_up, EPC_Drawing, Turbocharger_no_Type, Engine_Specific_Requirement, 
        //       Draft_sketch_with_details, Air_cooler_type, Description_of_Job 
        // FROM JDS_Data WHERE AUR_No 

        string str = "SELECT * fROM JDS_Data WHERE AUR_No like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        OleDbDataReader dr = mdlconnection.getRecord(str);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: string str = "SELECT * fROM JDS_Data WHERE AUR_No like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            OleDbDataReader dr = mdlconnection.getRecord(str);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Please Format your code

Comment: how to format it...i didnt foun dany option here

Comment: i have edited ..please help me

Comment: @shweta debug and check what is null. I assume dr can be null. Also post some description with the question when you post the question on SO.

Comment: Where is dataGridView1 defined and assigned?
Also, you might want to add a global catch to your application and report the stack trace.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please to be precise, what exactly are you plan to do.  I'll suggest you put your code in a try...catch block

```
try
{
    //code goes here
}
Catch(exception e) 
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```